# joomla: How to force a php webpage to save as a pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, joomla, content-type, mime-types

As an example, I have actually been able to generate excel files by changing the content-type for an html document.  In this scenario, I would use php to generate the table cells with information gathered from the database and then set the content-type before the page is rendered.  Is there a way to do this for pdf's?

Comment: Please elaborate it's a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to generate PDF is by using DOMPDF. [Learn more about DomPDF on Google's Projects](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

It is extremely simple:

1. Generate HTML page
2. Make a call to DomPDF
3. Download/Save your PDF

[Here is demo showing how easy and fast it is](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/examples.php#demo).

---

Because you are using Joomla you can create PDF view.

Create view called `view.pdf.php` in the view directory, include template and PDF will be generated automatically. Unfortunately Joomla's PDF is very plain... just text, images and other basic elements.

Comment: i develope dompdf in my site using this link [link]http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_PDF_views and my link is here [link]http://joomla5.guru99.com/software-testing-introduction-importance.html  And have button at the last in footer By pressing button  "Create pdf"  but it not include the header and footer of my site how can i include it in my pdf file

Answer (score 1):

> have actually been able to generate excel files by changing the content-type for an html document.

Well, not really: You have been building a HTML file, that Excel happens to be able to parse, and wrongly declaring it as a native Excel file. (I mean no criticism with this - the method works fine within its limitations - but to be exact. :)

As far as I know, this is not possible to do for PDF. You'll have to [generate a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+generate+pdf) using a library, or send the page to a PDF printer on the client's side.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple HTML then I suggest you use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate your PDF output. Just check out example 6 and 61 on the [TCPDF examples page](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples) to see how easy it is to generate PDFs based on a subset of HTML.

Comment: If I go in this direction, how do I format the data?  For example, the report I am creating needs certain sections to display within tables with black borders.  It would also be helpful if I could display checkboxes and/or radio buttons.  Would this be possible?  At the very least, how can I display the tables with black borders?

Comment: Look at the examples first, because they already show how you add tables with colored/black borders, and lots more. As for checkboxes and radiobuttons, the easiest way to embed these is to replace them by images, though you could also use a font that has these glyphs and render them that way (but that will take some trial and error).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library to generate the PDF document.  You can't just change the content-type like you did for Excel.

Try http://www.fpdf.org/

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

As well an [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) there's also [tcpdf](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) which is worth checking out.

Also, if you are interested in generating actual Excel files then have a look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).